# DataFrame.groupby.agg(list) works but not agg('list')

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was trying to apply what listagg does in SQL in pandas

Why does the following work

```
DataFrame.groupby.agg(list)
```

but the following does not?

```
DataFrame.groupby.agg('list')
```

I was transforming data below:
[image: Digital tracking data]

to
[image]

Comment: mind sharing ur data and code so we can understand what u r trying to replicate

Comment: my guess is that `list` is a function that can be applied to a collection of items. `'list'` is a string. If its a string, pandas checks a list of predefined functions like `'mean'` or `'std'`. `'list'` is not in this list of predefined functions. You can pass your own function to `agg()` and that should work too

Comment: @sammywemmy I edited the post with screenshot of the data I was working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If a parameter of the `.agg()` method is a **name of a function** (i. e. not a string with its name), it must be a *known name for Python,* i. e. a standard, imported, or your own function.
  (In your case, `list` is the standard Python function.)
- If a parameter of the `.agg()` method is a **string**, then pandas

  1. uses *a method of the `GroupBy` class,* if the method with such name exists
     (in your case, there is not a `.list()` method of the `GroupBy` class),
  2. uses a NumPy function with such name, if the function with such name exists
     (in your case, there is not a function `numpy.list()`)

As you may see, if the parameter is a string, Pandas ignores functions known to Python.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the pandas source code and found that, at least when aggregating a pandas Series, the string function name is "translated" to a function by calling

```py
if isinstance(func, str):
    return getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs)
```

where `self` is an instance of `SeriesGroupBy` which is a subclass of `GroupBy`. The `GroupBy` class has a number of methods that one would use for aggregation (including `count`, `mean`, `median`, etc.). `list` on the other hand is of course not a method of `GroupBy` but rather a built-in Python function, so its not found by the call to `getattr()`. I assume this is also the case for `DataFrameGroupBy`, since it's also a subclass of `GroupBy`.

In a similar way, `.agg()` would not be able to use any user-defined function name when provided as a string.

For a list of all available strings to provide to `.agg()`, check out [this article in the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html).